# Docker centos7 systemctl deos not work : Failed to connect D-bus

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, dbus, systemctl

I am trying to run elasticsearch on docker.

My features like below

- host system : OSX 10.12.5
- docker : 17.05.0-ce
- docker operating image : `centos:latest`

I was following [this article](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-elastic-stack-on-centos-7/), but it stuck with `systemctl daemon-reload`.

I found CentOS [official respond](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/centos#systemd-integration) about this `D-bus` bug, but when I ran `docker run` command it shows the message below.

`[!!!!!!] Failed to mount API filesystems, freezing.`

How could I solve this problem?

FYI, Here is `Dockerfile` what I build image

```
FROM centos
MAINTAINER juneyoung <juneyoung@hanmail.net>

ARG u=elastic
ARG uid=1000
ARG g=elastic
ARG gid=1000
ARG p=elastic

# add USER
RUN groupadd -g ${gid} ${g}
RUN useradd -d /home/${u} -u ${uid} -g ${g} -s /bin/bash ${u}


# systemctl settings from official Centos github
# https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/centos#systemd-integration
ENV container docker
RUN (cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/; for i in *; do [ $i == \
systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service ] || rm -f $i; done); \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/*;
VOLUME [ "/sys/fs/cgroup" ]



# yum settings
RUN yum -y update
RUN yum -y install java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64
ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-3.b12.el7_3.x86_64/jre/

# install wget
RUN yum install -y wget

# install net-tools : netstat, ifconfig
RUN yum install -y net-tools

# Elasticsearch install
ENV ELASTIC_VERSION=5.4.0
RUN rpm --import https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch
RUN wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-${ELASTIC_VERSION}.rpm
RUN rpm -ivh elasticsearch-${ELASTIC_VERSION}.rpm


CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]
```

and I have ran with command

`docker run -ti -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro --name=elastic2 elastic2`

Comment: Why you need `systemd` inside container? It's not the regular approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, thanks to @Robert. 
I did not think it that way.

All I have to do is just edit my `CMD` command.

Change that to 

`CMD["elasticsearch"]`

However, have to some chores to access from the browser.
refer [this elasticsearch forum post](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/running-elastic-5-4-on-centos-docker-installed-by-binary-file-does-not-bound/88206/4).

Comment: I think this is not an answer, but at least able to detour. And since there is no more answers, I close this question.

Answer (score 1):

You could follow the commands for a systemd-enabled OS if you would replace the normal systemctl command. That's how I do install elasticsearch in a centos docker container.

See ["docker-systemctl-replacement"](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement) for the details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and fancy implementation. I did not use it yet but looks good. I like the way you explain the causes. Thanks!